# Multiple &(AND) fails in query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, ms-access, conditional-statements

here is my query

```
$sql  =  'SELECT *
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderNumber = [Order Details].OrderNumber
WHERE 
Orders.CartID =2 
AND [Order Details].Option10 Is Null  
AND [Order Details].Status="Shipped"';
```

this queries when entered in MS_Access sql view, returns the correct results,
but when I copy and paste the same query in my php script, it fails and gives the error

> Too few parameters, expected 1...

although data is there, query is working in access...

Please note if I omitted on `AND` condition, it works eg if I removed `shipped` conidtion or `is null` condition, it works then too..

any hint? whats wrong with it?? any help?thanks

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with your PHP syntax. Can you post the rest of the syntax used to execute the query?

Comment: bro, it same, and after this line, I just execute odbc query

Comment: @Ioktenast '$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$sql  =  "SELECT *
//-------^ double quote here

...

AND [Order Details].Status='Shipped';";
//--- single quotes here --^-------^
//---------- double quote here ------^
```

Comment: thanks a million..it works like a charm,..but can you please answer me just one more thing...what I think and know is single qoute and double qoute both are same..and can be replaced....then why this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778521/difference-between-single-qoute-and-double-qoute

Comment: In some languages, they are interchangeable. In Transact-SQL, they are not. Single quote `'` is a string delimiter. Double quote `"` is an identifier. Try: `SELECT 'single', "double";`